# Play 1.2.5 and Jedis

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x, jedis

Simple question but how do I use Jedis with the play framework?

In the dependencies file I added

```
require:
...
- jedis -> jedis 2.1.0
```

Then I run `play deps` its not downloading the dependency.

I'm sure it is something simple but what am I doing wrong here.

Using Play Framework 1.2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry simple mistake in path to central maven repository.

should have been:

```
- redis.clients -> jedis 2.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the **play deps** will download the module for you.
You have to use **play install-module** instead.

However I think there might be an issue with the module repository at the moment so you might be better off [downloading](http://www.playframework.com/modules/redis) it yourself.